# In the UK, what's the rationale for having Crown Copyright?

Tags: united-kingdom, copyright

One major difference in copyright laws between the US and the UK is the scope of copyright on works created by government employees. In the US, nearly every government work enters the public domain by default, while in the UK all government works are protected under "crown copyright" for 50 years.

But what's the rationale for having a copyright on the state's works? Didn't the taxpayers already pay for it through their taxes? I'm mostly interested in the UK government's official position on this question.

Comment: This is by no means a full answer, but doesn't the state also have a duty to recover value from works like ordinance survey maps, rather than just handing them away for free? Not that your position isn't valid, but there are others.

Comment: @origimbo: Such maps have inherent value, since they allow some economic transactions (think real estate) to happen more easily than they otherwise might.  Making them freely available seems like an obvious win for the economy.

Comment: @Kevin, given that such maps would be duplicated in China, or distributed by google, wouldn't that be a win for someone else's economy?

Comment: @origimbo: Whose economy is going to benefit from a planning map of some part of the UK?

Comment: Don't know about the UK's stated position but the US is an exception here. Reasons to retain copyright include recovering money from foreign users and getting users to pay in relation to the extent of their use, thus saving the taxpayer money rather than providing an implicit subsidy to heavy users. It's not unusual either: think road tolls, copay in healthcare, entrance fees in museum (not in the UK obviously as entrance is free there), cheap meals in schools.

Comment: @origimbo Doesn't really matter, even a cheap map printed in China is a win for the world's economy. The point is that the UK benefits by making transactions easier and saving an entire industry a lot of money. The fact that China also wins or captures part of the value doesn't detract from Kevin's point, it's not a zero-sum game.

Comment: @Relaxed I've heard from numerous researches that the lack of state copyright in the US makes it a lot easier to conduct certain kinds of research there, e.g. mineralogy and other geo sciences.

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, obviously, researchers like that, I also wish governments the world around would force open access on the industry but I am not sure I see any contradiction with what I've written?

Comment: @Relaxed no contradiction, just pointing out one more issue with state copyright

Comment: I bet the copyright law in UK would be quite strict, as they are very lax in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two justifications for a Crown Copyright.

First, the benefit from use of materials subject to Crown Copyright is very unevenly distributed. So requiring those who use Crown Copyright material commercially to pay licensing fees prevents the U.K. government from using taxes collected from the general public rather evenly to subsidize the few who benefit commercially from this work. In this respect, a Crown Copyright is similar to users fees imposes for all manner of other government services (e.g. subway fares).

Second, a Crown Copyright affords the U.K. a significant degree of control over how economically and academically important information is used, for example, by denying licenses to academic crackpots. This is a kind of distinction that the U.S. political ethos of freedom of speech and freedom of the press is much more uncomfortable with government considering.